# How can I undo a marker created in javascript google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I made a google map using JavaScript. The moment the user left-clicks the map it will be added a pin, therefore I want when he right-click that marker to be deleted.

I've made this by now, only adding the marker.

```
 <script>
       
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            var coords;
            var next = document.getElementById('next');
           
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 40.7142700, lng: -74.0059700},
            zoom: 4
          });


          var marker;

map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    let lat = event.latLng.lat();
    let lng = event.latLng.lng();
   placeMarker(event.latLng,map);

  
    
   next.onclick = function() {
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
              if(socket !== undefined)
              {
                console.log('Connected to Live Server');
             socket.emit('pin-coords',{
                 lat:lat,
                 lng:lng
             });

             socket.on('redirect', function(destination) {
                 console.log('am ajuns aici');
                 window.location.href = destination;
             })

            
                  
                 
              }
   };
});



function placeMarker(location,map) {

 if (marker == null)
 {
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
  });

   
} else {   marker.setPosition(location); } }
        }

      </script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
      async defer>
</script>
```

I really don't know from where to start, I mean I'm thinking in the map.addListener('click')...
I should add another listener for deleting because there I have the coordinates, but couldn't find something in the docs. The only way is by using

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

,but my function placeMarker doesn't return a marker, and also couldn't find a key code for right click. I would be glad and thankful if you can help me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the marker's map property to null on a [right click](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.rightclick), add an event listener to the marker to listen for the `rightclick` event.  Inside the event listener callback function, the `this` will refer to the marker, call `this.setMap(null);`.

```
marker.addListener('rightclick', function() {
  this.setMap(null);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/01j9rfpL/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var coords;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.7142700,
      lng: -74.0059700
    },
    zoom: 4
  });


  var marker;

  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    let lat = event.latLng.lat();
    let lng = event.latLng.lng();
    placeMarker(event.latLng, map);
  });

  function placeMarker(location, map) {

    if (marker == null) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
      });
      marker.addListener('rightclick', function() {
        this.setMap(null);
      })
    } else {
      marker.setPosition(location);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<p>Click on the map to add markers.</p>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```